# Pydicom.read_file is only working with some Dicom images

Tags: python, pydicom

I am making a python application that can convert a .dcm image to .jpg using the pydicom library. This is my code:

```
import pydicom
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = 'testDicom.dcm'

#get pixel data from image
ds = pydicom.read_file(filename, force=True)
image = ds.pixel_array

new_img = []
max_value = None
min_value = None

#get maximum and minimum pixel values
for i in image:
    for l in i:
        if max_value:
            if l > max_value:
                max_value = l
        else:
            max_value = l

        if min_value:
            if l < min_value:
                min_value = l
        else:
            min_value = l

#use maximum and minimum pixel values to map pixel values between 0 and 255
for i in image:
    row = []
    for pixel in i:
        row.append((pixel - min_value) / (max_value / 255.0))
    new_img.append(row)

#convert to numpy array
new_img = np.array(new_img)

#save image
cv2.imwrite(filename.replace('.dcm', '.jpg'), new_img)
```

I have tested it on two files. The first one,

```
https://github.com/MaxwellMarcus/Training-Data-Creator/blob/master/testDicom.dcm
```

worked fine.

The second one,

```
https://github.com/MaxwellMarcus/Training-Data-Creator/blob/master/testDicom2.dcm
```

gave an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max Marcus\github\Training-Data-Creator\creator.py", line 6, in <module>
    image = ds.pixel_array
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py", line 1615, in pixel_array
    self.convert_pixel_data()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py", line 1324, in convert_pixel_data
    self._convert_pixel_data_without_handler()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py", line 1409, in _convert_pixel_data_without_handler
    raise RuntimeError(msg + ', '.join(pkg_msg))
RuntimeError: The following handlers are available to decode the pixel data however they are missing required dependencies: GDCM (req. GDCM)
```

Does anybody know why this is happening on only one of the two files, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 15):

You have a dataset that contains compressed *Pixel Data*. By itself *pydicom* can only handle *Pixel Data* that hasn't been compressed, but if you [install one or more optional libraries](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/tutorials/installation.html#install-the-optional-libraries) then it can handle various compressions. [This table](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/old/image_data_handlers.html#supported-transfer-syntaxes) tells you which package is required.

For *JPEG Lossless, Non-hierarchical, 1st Order Prediction* (1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70), the only listed package available is GDCM, which unfortunately means you either require a Conda install (and on conda-forge its [only available on Windows up to Python 3.6](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdcm/files)) or linux. Fortunately, there's an new package that I've been working on that also supports JPEG Lossless: [pylibjpeg](https://github.com/pydicom/pylibjpeg) with the [-libjpeg](https://github.com/pydicom/pylibjpeg-libjpeg) plugin.

```
$ pip install pylibjpeg pylibjpeg-libjpeg pydicom
```

```py
from pydicom import dcmread
import pylibjpeg

ds = dcmread("testDicom2.dcm")
arr = ds.pixel_array
```

Looking at your data, I'd say the *Photometric Interpretation* value is wrong, too. Change it to YBR_FULL first:

```py
from pydicom import dcmread
import pylibjpeg

ds = dcmread("testDicom2.dcm")
ds.PhotometricInterpretation = 'YBR_FULL'
arr = ds.pixel_array
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However, I am still facing the same error after following your suggestions. Any clue to fix this?

Comment: You could try `pip install python-gdcm`, which is a new project that builds the Python wrappers for GDCM and should have wheels available on Windows up to Python 3.9

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I had installed python-gdcm and pylibjpeg, however the error is still there. Have been looking around for the solution but still no luck (I am using python 3.7)

Comment: You don't have a `gdcm` folder in your working directory by any chance?

Comment: Hi, the installed gdcm is in my installation directory, but not the working directory where I store/read those DICOM files.

Comment: I'd try updating everything (pydicom, pylibjpeg, pylibjpeg-libjpeg, pylibjpeg-openjpeg), and if the issue still occurs create a new [issue](https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/issues/new/choose)?

Comment: I always had associated JPEG with lossy compression. Since JPEGs do in fact support lossless, do you an idea on the benefits of PNG at that point?

Comment: PNG is not a supported compression method for standard DICOM transfer syntaxes

Answer (score 2):

Second image is compressed dicom image and pydicom uses different packages such as GDCM and Pillow(for jpg, jpeg) for processing these images.

Installing one of the packages would solve the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I ran the command you suggested and I got this error:  [Error](https://github.com/MaxwellMarcus/Training-Data-Creator/blob/master/error.txt)

Comment: what do you use for installing pakages pip or conda
if you are working on conda then you can have a look at this https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdcm

Comment: And I am using python 3.6.10 and you are working on 3.7 and as per the error. GDCM is only available for python version=[2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|3.4.*]

Comment: please try this: https://github.com/pydicom/pydicom/wiki/Installing-the-Python-GDCM-bindings-without-Conda

Comment: This appears to be for Linux. I am currently running Windows 10. Do you know any way to get around this?

Comment: What's the *Transfer Syntax UID* for the dataset you're having issues with?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I find that?

Comment: Its *JPEG Lossless, non-hierarchical, 1st order prediction*

Comment: Is this the correct thing: (0002, 0010) Transfer Syntax UID                 UI: Explicit VR Little Endian

Comment: On anaconda after receiving the same error, I was able to run mine properly using `conda install -c conda-forge gdcm`.