# Reading CT Scan dicom file

Tags: python, pydicom

i am trying to read CT scan Dicom file using pydicom python library but i just can't get rid of this below error even when i install gdcm and pylibjpeg

```
RuntimeError: The following handlers are available to decode the pixel data however they are missing required dependencies: GDCM (req. ), pylibjpeg (req. )
```

Here is my code

```
!pip install pylibjpeg pylibjpeg-libjpeg pylibjpeg-openjpeg
!pip install python-gdcm

import gdcm
import pylibjpeg

import numpy as np
import pydicom
from pydicom.pixel_data_handlers.util import apply_voi_lut

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


def read_xray(path, voi_lut = True, fix_monochrome = True):
    dicom = pydicom.read_file(path)
    
    # VOI LUT (if available by DICOM device) is used to transform raw DICOM data to "human-friendly" view
    if voi_lut:
        data = apply_voi_lut(dicom.pixel_array, dicom)
    else:
        data = dicom.pixel_array
               
    # depending on this value, X-ray may look inverted - fix that:
    if fix_monochrome and dicom.PhotometricInterpretation == "MONOCHROME1":
        data = np.amax(data) - data
        
    data = data - np.min(data)
    data = data / np.max(data)
    data = (data * 255).astype(np.uint8)
        
    return data

img = read_xray('/content/ActiveTB/2018/09/17/1.2.392.200036.9116.2.6.1.44063.1797735841.1537157438.869027/1.2.392.200036.9116.2.6.1.44063.1797735841.1537157440.863887/1.2.392.200036.9116.2.6.1.44063.1797735841.1537154539.142332.dcm')
plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
plt.imshow(img)
```

Here is the image link on which i am trying to run this code

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-xuryA5VlglaumU2HHV7-p6Yhgd6AaCC/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Looks like you need to install `GDCM` and `pylibjpeg`

Comment: Actually you need only one of them. Check the documentation for installing [pylibjpeg](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/tutorials/installation.html#installing-pylibjpeg) or [GDCM](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/tutorials/installation.html#installing-gdcm).

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following:

```
!pip install pylibjpeg
!pip install gdcm
```

Comment: That is not entirely correct - see the documentation links in my comment above.

Comment: Hi, Thankyou for taking this question, I tried luke way also but the error still persist, I got rid of the error in conda. I did the same thing what I was doing in Google colab and pycharm. At last conda solve my problem, but I don't know the reason why it worked on conda and fail on colab and pycharm.

Comment: No, That runtime error was the only error that I was getting while converting. i did the same thing in conda and it was up and running.

Answer (score 0):

In a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62159709/pydicom-read-file-is-only-working-with-some-dicom-images) as yours, we could see that the problem persists at the *Pixel Data* level. You need to [install one or more optional libraries](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/tutorials/installation.html#install-the-optional-libraries), so that you can handle the various compressions.

First, you should do:

```
$ pip uninstall pycocotools
$ pip install pycocotools --no-binary :all: --no-build-isolation
```

From here, you should do as follows:

```
$ pip install pylibjpeg pylibjpeg-libjpeg pydicom
```

Then, your code should look like this:

```
from pydicom import dcmread
import pylibjpeg
import gdcm

import numpy as np
import pydicom
from pydicom.pixel_data_handlers.util import apply_voi_lut

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


def read_xray(path, voi_lut = True, fix_monochrome = True):
    dicom = dcmread(path)
    
    # VOI LUT (if available by DICOM device) is used to transform raw DICOM data to "human-friendly" view
    if voi_lut:
        data = apply_voi_lut(dicom.pixel_array, dicom)
    else:
        data = dicom.pixel_array
               
    # depending on this value, X-ray may look inverted - fix that:
    if fix_monochrome and dicom.PhotometricInterpretation == "MONOCHROME1":
        data = np.amax(data) - data
        
    data = data - np.min(data)
    data = data / np.max(data)
    data = (data * 255).astype(np.uint8)
        
    return data

img = read_xray('/content/ActiveTB/2018/09/17/1.2.392.200036.9116.2.6.1.44063.1797735841.1537157438.869027/1.2.392.200036.9116.2.6.1.44063.1797735841.1537157440.863887/1.2.392.200036.9116.2.6.1.44063.1797735841.1537154539.142332.dcm')
plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking this question i tried testing this code in colab but i got this ```ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject``` error. i tried updating/reinstalling NumPy (suggested on GitHub and StackOverflow) but still this error persist.

Comment: Try to follow this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/66060487/2371987

Comment: I tried this link, still, the error persists. Getting this error when I try to import pydicom.

Comment: Are you using conda?

Comment: Google collab, it is working fine in conda, i am facing this error in pycharm and colab.I am just curious why it is not working on colab and pycharm.

Comment: Try the following solution:

https://chadrick-kwag.net/valueerror-numpy-ndarray-size-changed-may-indicate-binary-incompatibility-error-fix/

Comment: Still, the error persists.

Comment: Did you try with other `.dcm` example? You have a bunch of available **DICOM** file examples that you can try.

Comment: Yeah I did, there's one thing I forgot to mention, this reading Dicom file error is when I try to read CT scan slices, when I try reading X-Rays it works.